# How to extract certain values from a table using the SearchCursor Tool

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy, arcgis-10.2, cursor

I am trying to write a python script to extract certain values from a table: the table I am referring to is a big collection of nitrate values for different water depths, which are deposited in the columns of the table. As I only need the value of the surface and the deepest point, I want to search through the rows and extract the last value that is not 0. I have started writing a script using the SearchCursor Tool but get stuck at the point, where I want it to search for the first 0-value and then go back and print the value fro mthe column before... Does anyone have an idea how to solve that problem?

```
import arcpy

# Set the Workspace
arcpy.env.workspace = "D:\Teresa\Kerstin\SouthernOcean\03_workspace\Teresa"

# Make table
table = "C:/Users/theidema/Desktop/OxzUti_GridP_Annual.csv"

#Create the search cursor
cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(Table)

#Iterate through the rows
row = cursor.next()
while row:
    print (row.getValue(field))
    row = cursor.next()
```

Here is a Screenshot of the table (depths go down until 5500M)

[image]

Comment: Teresa, what is your version of ArcGIS?

Comment: could you please add an view of your table to illustrate your problem? I don't understand if you need to iterate on the columns or on the rows. What version of ArcGIS are you using ?

Comment: I am using the 10.2.1. Version!

Comment: You may want to think about using [Summary Statistics](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000001z000000) (MAX—Finds the largest value for all records of the specified field) rather than ArcPy to get this but I am not 100% clear on your requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list_of_fields_with_depth = (x.name for x in arcpy.Listfields(Table, "wildcard"))
cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(Table, list_of_fields_with_depth)

#Iterate through the rows

for row in rows:
    for i in range(len(list_of_fields_with_depth)):
        if ( (row[i] == 0) and (i>0) ):
            print row[i-1]
            break
        else:
            print "no zero on this line"
```